# VueJS: observer object instead of Array

Tags: arrays, vuejs2

I have this small one page VueJS app which uses Firebase. The problem I am currently facing is when I try to retrieve a collection from Firebase in a component. Instead of returning an array, the vue instance returns an observer object, more precisely `[__ob__: Observer]`. I understand that Vue JS uses this object to do its magic, what I don't understand is what am I supposed to do to get the actual array. I cannot do anything with that object, can't iterate it. I tried any lifecycle method to try and do it, but no luck. What is weirder is that when I close and open again the Chrome console (F12), the methods get called again and the object is actually resolved into the array. I initially thought that the data may not be retrieved yet, but the data is present in the object itself, I just can't access it.

Here's my code:

Vue instance:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  firebase: {
    orders: firebase.database.ref('orders').orderByChild('created_at'),
    members: firebase.database.ref('members').orderByChild('created_at')
  },
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

Component code:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      'member': null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isMemberLoaded: function () {
      this.member !== null
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    console.log('mounted')
    this.init()
    console.log(this.$root.members) // [__ob__: Observer]
  },
  created: function () {
    console.log('created')
    console.log(this.$root.members) // [__ob__: Observer]
  },
  updated: function () {
    console.log('updated')
    console.log(this.$root.members) // [__ob__: Observer]
  },
  methods: {
    init: function () {
      console.log('init')
      console.log(this.$root.members) // [__ob__: Observer]
    }
  }
}
```

The observer object looks like this:

```
[__ob__: Observer]
    0:
      .key:(...)
      code:(...)
      created_at:(...)
      email:(...)
      name:(...)
      __ob__:Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
      get .key: ƒ reactiveGetter()
      set .key: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
      get code: ƒ reactiveGetter()
      set code: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
      get created_at: ƒ reactiveGetter()
      set created_at: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
      get email: ƒ reactiveGetter()
      set email: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
      get name: ƒ reactiveGetter()
      set name: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
      __proto__: Object
      length: 1
    __ob__: Observer {value: Array(1), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
    __proto__: Array
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: is the observer object empty ?

Comment: @GeorgiAntonov, no, the data is in there.

Comment: so what is the problem ? access the array which is in the observer object

Comment: @GeorgiAntonov can't, check my post again to see how the object looks

Comment: instead of using `this.$root` use `this.$firebaseRefs`

Comment: are you using Vuefire ?

Comment: @GeorgiAntonov yes

Comment: then try my answer never played with it but checked docs and it seems you can access your firebase data using this.$firebaseRefs in every component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154443/discussion-between-georgi-antonov-and-comforse).

Answer (score 5):

Simply do:

```
var parsedObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$root.members))
console.log(parsedObj)
```

It will convert the *[**ob**: Observer]* to its value

Comment: Sure, but even better, I will let Evan You (creator of VueJS) answer : [here](https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/292)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this firebase thing works. but im sure you can access the $firebase object with `this` in each component because it is obviously global and find your data there.

```
export default {
      data () {
        return {
          'member': null
        }
      },
      firebase: {
         members: db.ref('members')
       },
      computed: {
        isMemberLoaded: function () {
          this.member !== null
        }
      },
      mounted: function () {
        console.log('mounted')
        this.init()
        console.log(this.$root.members) // [__ob__: Observer]
      },
      created: function () {
        console.log('created')
        console.log(this.$root.members) // [__ob__: Observer]
      },
      updated: function () {
        console.log('updated')
        console.log(this.$root.members) // [__ob__: Observer]
      },
      methods: {
        init: function () {
          console.log('init')
          console.log(this.$root.members) // [__ob__: Observer]
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, with the help of @Georgi Antonov I managed to solve my issue in this way:

I changed my component like this:

```
methods: {
    init: function () {
      let _vm = this
      let _id = _vm.$route.params.id
      _vm.$root.$firebaseRefs.members.child(_id).on('value', function (d) {
        console.log(d.val())
      })
    }
  }
```

The essential parts is `_vm.$root.$firebaseRefs.members`. This actually resolves in a firebase object (collection?) and from there you can access the data. The `child` function just retrieves the element with the passed id. It's not an array, but I don't require one as I don't need to search. In order to get the entire list just change to `_vm.$root.$firebaseRefs.members.on('value', function() {}`.

While Georgi Antonov provided the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46218260/1475898), that is not quite correct. The firebase references are defined in the Vue instance and you don't need to declare them again in the component. Hence, `this` would not have the firebase refs in the scope.